# Is it possible to add a line to my script to prevent windows sleep during the job?

Tags: batch-file

I have a Batch file that works for me as intended. The only problem is that as jobs take sometimes a long time to complete, windows will go to sleep while the job is being done. I was wondering if it's possible to add a command to disable windows from sleeping and turn the option back when the job is done? Like adding powercfg /change standby-timeout-dc 0 at the beginning and powercfg /change standby-timeout-dc 20 at the end of the script?!

Anyway I will paste the script. Please take a look and see what is needed to be added to get this work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "t0=%TIME%, %DATE%"
set "RestoreFolder="
set "ProxyDir=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Proxy"
if not exist "%ProxyDir%" mkdir "%ProxyDir%"

rem Is the batch file started without any argument (or with first argument
rem being an empty string)? Yes, process all video files in current directory.
if "%~1" == "" goto AllFiles

rem Is the batch file started not with a folder name as first argument?
rem Yes, the first argument is most likely a file name and so just a
rem single file should be processed by the batch file.
if not exist "%~1\" goto SingleFile

rem The batch file is started with a folder name as first argument.
rem Make this folder the current directory using command PUSHD and
rem if that is successfull process all video files in that folder.
pushd "%~1" 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 set "RestoreFolder=1" & goto AllFiles

echo ERROR: Failed to make "%~1" the current directory!
echo/
pause
exit /B 1

:AllFiles
for %%i in (*.mp4 *.avi *.mov *.wmv *.ts *.m2ts *.mkv) do if not exist "%ProxyDir%\%%~ni_proxy.mp4" (
    if /I not "%%~xi" == ".avi" (
        "%~dp0nvencc\NVEncC64.exe" -i "%%i" -o "%ProxyDir%\%%~ni_proxy.mp4" --output-res 960x-2 -c h264 --preset quality --cqp 23:25:28 --aq-strength 10 --ref 1 --bframes 0 --gop-len 15 --lookahead 15 --qp-max 30 --aq --cabac --mv-precision q-pel --audio-codec aac --audio-bitrate 384 --avsync cfr --colorprim auto --transfer auto --colormatrix auto --colorrange auto
    ) else (
        "%~dp0nvencc\NVEncC64.exe" -i "%%i" -o "%ProxyDir%\%%~ni_proxy.mp4" --output-res 960x-2 -c h264 --preset quality --cqp 23:25:28 --aq-strength 10 --ref 1 --bframes 0 --gop-len 15 --lookahead 15 --qp-max 30 --aq --cabac --mv-precision q-pel --audio-codec aac --audio-bitrate 384 --avsync cfr
    )
)
if defined Restorefolder popd
goto OutputInfo

:SingleFile
if exist "%~1" goto ProcessFile
echo ERROR: Could not find "%~1"!
echo/
pause
exit /B 1

:ProcessFile
if not exist "%ProxyDir%\%~n1_proxy.mp4" (
    if /I not "%~x1" == ".avi" (
        "%~dp0nvencc\NVEncC64.exe" -i "%~1" -o "%ProxyDir%\%~n1_proxy.mp4" --output-res 960x-2 -c h264 --preset quality --cqp 23:25:28 --aq-strength 10 --ref 1 --bframes 0 --gop-len 15 --lookahead 15 --qp-max 30 --aq --cabac --mv-precision q-pel --audio-codec aac --audio-bitrate 384 --avsync cfr --colorprim auto --transfer auto --colormatrix auto --colorrange auto
    ) else (
        "%~dp0nvencc\NVEncC64.exe" -i "%~1" -o "%ProxyDir%\%~n1_proxy.mp4" --output-res 960x-2 -c h264 --preset quality --cqp 23:25:28 --aq-strength 10 --ref 1 --bframes 0 --gop-len 15 --lookahead 15 --qp-max 30 --aq --cabac --mv-precision q-pel --audio-codec aac --audio-bitrate 384 --avsync cfr
    )
)

:OutputInfo
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe write-host -fore cyan  ====================== Processing is FINISHED =======================
echo ----------------------------
echo Batch processing start time: %t0%
echo Batch processing end time:   %TIME%, %DATE%
echo ----------------------------
endlocal
@ECHO OFF
:myLabel
SHUTDOWN /S /F /T 600
SET /P continue="Your computer is about to shutdown in 10 min do you want to abort (y/n): "
IF %continue% EQU y (
SHUTDOWN /A

)
```

This script, (apart from the bottom eight lines), was already created for me by a member [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809997/). I personally have no idea on how to modify it. So I personally have not tried anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "powercfg /change" commands you listed should work. The first usage goes on a new line after the "@echo off" and the last command goes at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your reply. It worked perfectly well. I just made a little mistake: powercfg /change standby-timeout-dc 0  (had to change dc to ac)